# Elasticsearch: how to know which field the results are sorted by?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

In Elasticsearch, is there any way to check which field the results are sorted by? I want something like inner-hits for sort clause.

Imagine that your documents have this kind of form:

```
{"numerals" : [  // nested
    {"key": "point", "value": 30},
    {"key": "points", "value": 200},
    {"key": "score", "value": 20},
    {"key": "scores", "value": 40}
  ]
}
```

and you sort the results by:

```
{"numerals.value": {
  "nested_path": "numerals",
  "nested_filter": {
    "match": {
      "numerals.key": "score"}}}}
```

Now I have no idea how to know the field by which the results are actually sorted: it's probably `scores` at this document, but is perhaps `score` at the others? There are 2 problems - 1. You cannot use inner-hits nor highlight for the nested fields. and - 2. Even if you can, it doesn't solve the issue if there are multiple matching candidates.

Comment: What if you use a `term` query instead in your nested filter?

Comment: @Val well, I want to use `match`.

Comment: Fair enough, any reason why you have `score` and `scores`? Why not simply having the same term?

Comment: @Val The shown document is just a compromised example. The real ones are much more complicated. I cannot even expect what come to `key`s.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm just trying to see if there was a simple way around first ;-)

Comment: What's the mapping of the `numerals.key` field?

Comment: @Val It's `text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is about sorting by fields that are inside nested objects.

So this is what the documention
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-sorting.html
and
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_nested_sorting_example
says:

Elasticsearch will first restrict the nested documents by the "nested_filter"-query and then sort on the same way as for multi-valued fields:
Exactly the way as if there would be only the filtered nested documents as inner objects aka as if there would be only the root document with a multi-valued field which contains exactly all value which belong to the filtered nested objects
( in your example there will only one value remain: 20).
If you want to be sure about the sort order insert a "mode" parameter:
"min", "max", "sum", "avg" or "median"

If you do not specify the "mode" parameter according to the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/2634) the min-value will be picked for "asc" and the max-value will be picked for "desc"-order:

> By default when sorting on a multi-valued field the lowest or highest
>   value will be picked from the field values depending on the sort
>   order.

Comment: Interesting, but how do I know which `numerals.value`s are selected as the candidates for min-value and max-value, after all?

Comment: I updated the aswer: Because your nested_filter matches only on nested document the remaining value is "20". The "nested_filter" is used from elasticsearch independently from your (main-) query.